# How to pass parent id to Kendo UI child grid new record editor

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a TreeView that displays a list of database records. When a user selects a record, I populate a grid with the related record details. The foreign key is sourceid.

I pass the selected record's id like this:

```
.Read(read => read.Action("AquisitionNotes_Read", "AquisitionNotes").Data("GetCurrentSourceID"))
```

The GetCurrentSourceID function is simply:

```
function GetCurrentSourceID() {
   return {sourceid: currentSourceID };
}
```

That works.

But when I want to add a new record, how do I get the currentSourceID value into the Post? If I try the obvious:

```
.Create(update => update.Action("AquisitionNotes_Create", AquisitionNotes").Data("GetCurrentSourceID"))
```

The value from the editor (0 of course) gets precedence and gets passed.

How do I force my actual sourceid to overwrite the editor's value? Or am I solving the problem in the wrong way?

- Brad

Answer (score 0):

To pass the default value to the create you should use `DataSource`

for example

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid()
      .DataSource(data=>data.Ajax()
                        .Model(m=>{
                             m.Field(field=>field.Whatever).DefaultValue(TheValue);
            })))
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it figured out thanks to the lead that @user5135401 gave me.

user5135401's solution works if you want to set a static default value. I do not know of a way to do a dynamic default value form Razor. This is how you do it per [this forum post](http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-set-default-values-to-a-grid-when-adding-new-row):

Call a JS function from the grid's .Edit event like:

```
.Events(events => events.Edit("SetDefaultSourceID"))
```

Then that function returns the value, in my case the foreign key value of the selected TreeView item:

```
function SetDefaultSourceID(e) {
    if (e.model.isNew()) {
        //set the required field value
        e.model.set("sourceid", currentSourceID);
    }
}
```